# Reading CSV files in Pandas and/or Tableau With Diefferent Row Sizes

Tags: python, csv, pandas, tableau-api, large-files

I have a csv file which I want to read with Pandas library in Python.

In this table when we encounter a new item (e.g. items Nr. 1393 or 1654 in the example below) we first have a 4 column row metadata and after that several 100 column rows as real data associated to that item. Then it happens again for the next item and so on.

The table is like this:

```
1,1393,0,0
1,1393,1,22,55,63,...
1,1393,5,32,43,163,...
.
.
.
2,1654,0,0
2,1654,8,95,96,142,...
2,1654,21,31,364,9,...
.
.
.
```

So the problems are:

1. Some rows have different sizes than others
2. We do not have headers and can not create it as the first row has 4 entries and second one 100 entries
3. My CSV file is huge (about 10G)!

Any suggestion which helps me to organize my data in Pandas or any other Python library is highly appreciated.

PS: BTW, anybody knows how to manage it in Tableau?

Comment: To get this straight... you have 2 row sizes - 4 column metadata and all of the others are a fixed size >100? What do you want to do with the metadata? Add it to the columns or drop it?

Comment: You could create a subclass of csv.reader and override the next method so that all lines have the same number of columns.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes that's right and I want to drop them.

Comment: @DavidCullen Would you please explain more? maybe as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielWelke: I added an answer showing how to do what I described.

Answer (score 1):

When data doesn't fit an existing `pandas` reader, you can create your own generator and populate the dataframe with `from_records`. Lacking details on how these various items should be related, I wrote an example that just adds the latest metadata to the front of each row.

```
import pandas as pd

def my_data_generator(fp):
    metadata = []
    for line in fp:
        data = line.strip().split(',')
        if len(data) == 4:
            metadata = data
        elif not metadata:
            raise ValueError("csv file did not start with metadata")
        elif data:
            yield metadata + data

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_data_generator(open('somefile.csv')))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source, I found that csv.reader is not a class, but a method. However, I tested this solution:

```
import csv

class same_width_reader(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable, width=0, dialect='excel', *args, **kwargs):
        self._reader = csv.reader(iterable, dialect, *args, **kwargs)
        self.width = width

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        result = self._reader.next()
        if self.width:
            width = len(result)
            if width < self.width:
                result += ['0'] * (self.width - width)
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('input.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = same_width_reader(csv_file, 6)
        for line in reader:
            print line
```

For this input

```
1,1393,0,0
1,1393,1,22,55,63
1,1393,5,32,43,163
```

The program produces this output

```
['1', '1393', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['1', '1393', '1', '22', '55', '63']
['1', '1393', '5', '32', '43', '163']
```

It should be possible to adapt this solution to work with any other library that reads CSV files.